# Pervin quasi-uniformity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

for a subset $ A$  of a set $X$ we set
$S_{A} =[(X - A)×X]∪ [X ×A]$.

We recall that if $X$ is a topological space, then the Pervin quasi-uniformity of $X$ is generated by the subbase $\{S_{G}: G \quad\text{is an open subset of}\quad X \}$.

> Let $I = [0, 1]$ be the unit interval of the reals equipped with its
>   usual compact Hausdorff topology and let $P$ be its transitive Pervin
>   quasi-uniformity. Then $P ∧ P^{-1}$ is the unique compatible
>   uniformity on $I$, which is not transitive.

My question is:why is

> $P ∧ P^{-1}$  the unique compatible uniformity on $I$, which is not
>   transitive?

Comment: For every compact Hausdorff topological space there exists a unique compatible uniformity; it consists in the open neighbourhood of the diagonal (in the product space). This is proved by Nicolas Bourbaki, *Topologie générale*, Springer 2006, in Theorem 1, II.27. I think this answers at least part of your question.